# CSS Sprites Creation

Tags: web-development, images, css

I think this kind of tool is a must have for any web developer, and I would love to get a recommendation for a tool that would simplify the workflow

1. have a bunch of icons and images to spriteify
2. run software
3. create a .css and a .png sprite

I would rather it be free (there is a great, yet expensive, TexturePacker) and will able to create a sprite for retina screen as well
and work for OSX

I don't care if its with UI or command line (as long as its simple and one liner)

Comment: I can give you command line option that is a single line *after* it has been set-up; setup will take a few command line calls and generating a small text file; but it is very easy to do and I can give you pretty much exact copy & past contents (ie just replace a couple file paths with your own file paths).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tools, I was able to find:

Some of them are online:

- [zerosprites](http://zerosprites.com/)
- [spritepad](http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/)

And some are standalone

- [spritegenerator](http://spritegenerator.codeplex.com/)
- [spritemapper](http://yostudios.github.io/Spritemapper/)

I liked Zerosprites for few reasons:

- no need to install anything
- locates images automatically on the sprite, trying to minimize the size of image
- creates css
- allows you to optimize png
- it is free
- it is easy to use